# iCloud not syncing and folders are slow to refresh

Tags: icloud, finder

I am signed into my iCloud account and I have the Desktop and Documents folder is ticked.  It does not seem to be able to complete syncing to iCloud. If I look at the small information circle on the `iCloud Drive` in Finder, it says something like 'Uploading 27 items to iCloud (2.9GB of 38.4GB)'.  It has been like this for a month with the same message. If I go to Activity Monitor and kill `cloudd`, the message might change to (5.99GB of 38GB). Maybe it is stuck on a particular file?

As well, the Finder folders that are part of Documents are very slow to update, like it can take days for a folder to reflect changes, and if I try to load an application files I can see in the Finder do not appear in the app menu. This later bug appear even on folders not syncing to iCloud.

I am using a Mac Mini with OSX 12.12.3.

How do I fix these problems?